# .net can I add a typed row to a new (empty) data table?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatables, datarow

I want to create a new table from a row that came from another table.  In the example below `_DataRow` is a `Private` variable of the class.

Is this feasible, or do I need to define the columns of the data table first?

Example in vb.net

```vb
Public Sub CreateDataTableFromTypedRow()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Rows.Add(_DataRow)
End Sub
```

Example in C#

```
public void CreateDataTableFromTypedRow()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable;
    dt.Rows.Add(_DataRow);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone the `DataTable` and add the `ItemArray` of the existing row to it:

```
DataRow dr = _DataRow;
DataTable dt = dr.Table.Clone();
dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
```

Comment: Ah!  The Table.Copy() method looks like a great way to go.  So, the answer is YES, I must create the table first?

Comment: Yes, the columns of the imported row must match with the table's columns.

Comment: I assume DataRow dr = _DataRow; is not really required, and DataTable dt = dr.Table.Copy(); can be  DataTable dt = _DataRow.Table.Copy();

Comment: Yes, of course. dr is only a reference to _DataRow.

Comment: Wouldn't `.Clone()` be the right method for this case? AFAIK `.Copy()` also copies the contents of the table and `.Clone` only the structure.

Comment: MatSnow--if that's the case, then I can use Copy, and would NOT need to then add the Row, as the row would have been already added.  Correct?  Does the answer above, add the row twice?

Comment: That's correct. Use Clone() if you don't want to copy the other rows. I edited my answer.

Comment: If I use dr.Table.Copy(), per the original answer, I would then NOT need to add the row afterwards, as it will have been added with the copy() method

Comment: @EdwardBagby In response to the corrected comment: Yes

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, the other solution could simply be:

```
DataTable dt = _DataRow.Table.Copy();
```

Since the Copy() method will both clone the table and copy the row to that table.